# How should I continue my proof of this cycle property? (And did I make a mistake?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I am trying to show:

> For a given single cycle, such as $(1, 4, 5, 7)$, the order of such a cycle is the length of the cycle. (i.e $(1, 4, 5, 7)^4 = ()$).

I am trying to do this by induction.

> Proof:
>
> Base case, the cycle $()$ has an order of $0$.
>
> Now assume it holds true for a cycle of length $k$. Now consider:
>   $$(a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k, a_{k+1})^{k+1}$$
>   $$\implies (a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k, a_{k+1})^k (a_1, a_2, \ldots a_k, a_{k+1})$$
>   But we can decompose this into transpositions, namely:
>   $$[(a_1, a_{k+1})(a_1, a_k) \ldots (a_1 a_2)]^k (a_1, a_{k+1}) (a_1, a_k) \ldots (a_1, a_2)$$
>   $$ \implies (a_1, a_{k+1})^k[(a_1, a_k) \ldots (a_1 a_2)]^k (a_1, a_{k+1}) (a_1, a_k) \ldots (a_1, a_2)$$
>   But by the inductive hypothesis we have:
>   $$(a_1, a_{k+1})^k (a_1, a_{k+1}) (a_1, a_k) \ldots (a_1, a_2)$$

From here I am stuck. Also, I think I did something wrong, as I don't think my last statement must be $()$ all the time. $(a_1, a_{k+1})^{k+1}$ may cancel out, but either way your left with the cycle of length $k$. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to prove this by induction on the cycle length.  While you can certainly break up a $(k + 1)$-cycle into a $k$-cycle and a $2$-cycle it's not true that these cycles will commute!  So when you raise the $(k + 1)$-cycle to the $(k + 1)^\text{th}$ power it doesn't mean you'll get a $k^\text{th}$ power on your $k$-cycle, so you won't be able to use the inductive hypothesis.

In particular you have
$$[(a_1 \ a_{k + 1})(a_1 \ a_k)\cdots(a_1 \ a_2)]^k = (a_1 \ a_{k + 1})^k[(a_1 \ a_k)\cdots(a_1 \ a_2)]^k$$
but the $k^\text{th}$ power can't distribute like that.  For example $(1 \ 2 \ 3) = (1 \ 3)(1 \ 2)$ but $(1 \ 2 \ 3)^2 = (1 \ 3)^2(1 \ 2)^2 = ()$ is not true, $(1 \ 2 \ 3)^2 = (1 \ 3 \ 2)$.

Try proving that if $x = (a_n \ a_{n - 1} \cdots \ a_1)$ is an $n$-cycle and we set $a_{n + 1} = a_1$ then for any $0 \leq i \leq n$ we have $x(a_i) = a_{i + 1}$.  This you can prove by induction.

Comment: Thanks, I get it know! Sorry for the late reply some stuff came up.

Comment: Also, I would edit it (except it doesn't meet the minimum 6 chars needed), but I am fairly certain you mean $x(a_i)$ not $x(a_1)$.

Comment: That is what I meant, thanks :)